# 70s (or earlier) science fiction short story featuring a gem in a velvet box used for time travel or teleportation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to track down a science fiction story that I read in the mid-1970s and vaguely recall. This was a short story that was in a compilation book in my school library. The details that I remember are at the beginning of the story.

There is a small velvet box with a gem fixed inside of it (possibly an opal or pearl). I believe that there are two characters, a brother and a sister. There is some interaction where the characters are sitting on a park bench examining the velvet box.

I believe that the box is used for either time travel or transportation. There may also be a mysterious stranger that guides the characters through the use of the box.

I don't have much more recollection of the story, but please feel free to ask any clarifying questions and I'll try to assist.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)